# How do I read all the HTML files in a directory and write the content into a CSV file using Python?

Tags: python, csv, file-io

I am trying to read all the HTML files in a directory and write them into a CSV file. Each row in the CSV file will contain the contents of one HTML file.

I seem to be able to read one HTML file and write into a CSV file.

```py
import os, csv
import fnmatch
from pathlib import Path

directory = "directory/"

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.html'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as f:
            html = f.read()
            if 'apples and oranges' in html:
                with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
                    writer = csv.writer(f)
                    lines = [[html]]
                    for l in lines:
                        writer.writerow(l)
```

I currently only see one HTML file being printed out into one CSV row.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you used [`'w'` or write mode](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open).

```
with open('output.csv', 'w') as f:
```

That truncates the file and overwrites the previous contents.

You should be using [`'a'` or append mode](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open).

```
with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:
```

That opens the file for writing if it doesn't yet exist, or appends to the end of the file if it already exists.

Comment: I'm still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

When using open('output.csv', 'w'), this means that you rewrite to the file everytime this is executed, so every loop iteration. It's like saving new material to a file with the same name. The material that was in the file before you saved won't be visible after. You need to use open('output.csv', 'a') so that the file your writing to is only appended to, instead of being written over. If you do use append though, you want to remove the file if it already exists first, otherwise you're going to be appending to your old results.

Here's a working example, I added some extra formatting stuff to achieve the output that you describe in the question

```
import os
import fnmatch
import re


directory = "directory/"

#Remove the output file if it exists, otherwise you'll have output from the previous execution
if (os.path.exists('output.csv')):
    os.remove('output.csv')

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.html'):
        with open(os.path.join(dirpath, filename)) as f:
            html = [line.rstrip("\n") for line in f]    #Puts each line from the html file into a list
            lines = "".join(html)                       #Concats that list into a single string
            line = re.sub(" +", " ", lines)             #Gets rid of superfluous whitespace, but substituting any chains of spaces " +" for just one single space
            if re.search("apples and oranges", line):   
                with open('output.csv', 'a') as f:      #Changed w (which stand for write) to append. With w the file is rewritten every time it's called. With a the file only has text appended to the end
                    f.write(line + ",\n")

#Removes the comma and newline at the end of the file
with open("output.csv", 'rb+') as filehandle:
    filehandle.seek(-2, os.SEEK_END)
    filehandle.truncate()
```